# Set Error-Pages for all Applications in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, errordocument

I'm trying to set up custom error pages in tomcat 6, because I don't want the default ones to show up. My error pages are static html, no jsp or anything dynamic.

I know how to do this through the web.xml in each application but I'd prefere to setup the error pages only once for the entire server.

I tried to add the following fragment to the global web.xml (in conf), but no matter what I add under location, it does not show.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

What do I need to do to gobally define custom error pages? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct (and worked fine for me). But you will need a file called 404.html at the root level for every webapp deployed for it to work.

If you do NOT want to do that - there is the little know errorReportValveClass as part of StandardHost in which you can provide your own implementation of a class to handle all the uncaught errors.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html